# Upgrading to 4.7.21 on Wordpress get uncaught exception on status page

Tags: wordpress, upgrade

After uploading the 4.7.21 plugin the CiviCRM admin pages loaded ok with the status at bottom indicating new version and of course with a red 'System Status' warning. On clicking this to get to the status page to update db etc, got this error:
Uncaught exception: You have requested a non-existent service "asset_builder".

Tried installing clean copy again. Same result. Resolved issue by manually entering the upgrade page url. This brought up expected option to upgrade db. All well after this.
https://xxx/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/upgrade&reset=1

Question: is this just our installation or have others had same behaviour, and did this fix resolve?

Comment: After the upgrade, if accessing to System Status page again, it continues giving an error?

Comment: I experienced something similar, except I cannot get the system status page to populate at all. I had run the upgrade script by entering its URL manually, and it seemed to work on the second try except for a missing indices error -- but now I can't get my system status information. Posted a question [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19365/missing-indices-error-followed-by-missing-system-status-page)

Answer (score 1):

- Status page failed to load, giving an uncaught exception error.
- Loaded the upgrade url directly -->https://xxx/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/upgrade&reset=1.
- This ran the update
- Status page now loaded, with option to rebuild indices

Comment: Need to give time for the status page content to load after initial view