# Missing indices error followed by missing system status page

Tags: missing

Trying to implement the solution that worked when I got the missing indices error after the 4.7.20 update, but can't hit the Update button because System Status page isn't populating with anything. Haven't found a cause or solution for the empty System Status page. So I'm running 4.7.21 -- presumably with the missing indices error, and no way to fix it.

Suggestions?

Comment: Same issue here... anyone find a solution yet?

Comment: Just updated to 4.7.22, and no missing indices errors ... yet. System status page is loading fine as well.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds similar to [Status page angular load error](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19366/status-page-angular-load-error) and i will paste my answer here, though I think your 'question' is the wrong issue, ie this is angular issue, not missing indices issue.

We had one site that had 'lost' all it angular pages, eg CiviMail and System Status.

In our case the angular cache files were returning 404 on the New Mailing page. (and 'inspector' was showing a lot of red angular errors)

It was building the cache files in sites/default/files/civicrm/images, but then searching for them in sites/default/files/civicrm/persist/contribute

The issue here was a mismatch between the resource url setting for Image Upload URL and the directory setting for Image Directory. Strangely (!!) these folders are being used for caching of angular files.

Comment: Thank you, Pete -- I just saw your answer and was about to look at resource URL settings, when system status finally populated. I hadn't changed anything yet -- it just suddenly worked. No idea why.

Comment: Had a similar issue. Needed to refresh System Status 4 times before I got content

Comment: interesting - so you guys both got it back via patience +/- cache clearing - we have started a JIRA issue so that Upgrade includes clearing civi caches, which might improve such situations.

Comment: Also getting this error: 
Warning: file_get_contents(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in /home/site/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/VersionCheck.php on line 429

Warning: file_get_contents(https://latest.civicrm.org/stable.php?format=json): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in home/site/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/VersionCheck.php on line 429

Comment: Glad I discovered this. I got my System Status page to come back live by executing https://oursite.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/admin/setting/updateConfigBackend&reset=1, clicking both buttons, and then executing https://oursite.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/menu/rebuild&reset=1. For safety, as if I were moving our site, I also executed https://oursite.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/menu/rebuild&reset=1&triggerRebuild=1.

Comment: Karl - it would probably be good if you add your comment as an Answer

Comment: Hmmm, empty status page, as well, after upgrade CiviCRM 4.7.20 --> .22; I didn't have any issues with Angular, and repeated refreshes of the status page did not fix things either.  Per [Chat channel](https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/wordpress#) discussion with KCristiano, filling in the absolute paths for `[civicrm.root]` and `[civicrm.files]` on the Resource URL page did fix the issue for me.  Config:  Ubuntu 14.04.5 / LAMP on AWS t2 micro with WordPress 4.8.0 as CMS.