# screen for composing a mail is blank

Tags: civimail, upgrade, error, 4.7.21

I am using CiviCRM 4.7.21, on Drupal 7.56.
I am attempting to send a monthly mail-out.  If I choose last month's mail-out and click the "re-use" button, I get a blank screen:
[image: blank CiviCRM screen]

If I go to mailings->draft, my new mailing is listed there.  If I then click "continue", it goes to the same blank screen.  If I try using mailings->new mailing, again the same blank screen, and a new draft mailing that I can't edit.
This problem seems to have come up since I updated from 4.7.20 to 4.7.21 (updated 2 weeks ago, but this is the first new mailing we're trying to create since then).
If more information is needed in order to reply, please tell me how/where to find it.

thanks,
CMD

Comment: for drupal version try /admin/reports/status

Comment: thanks!  I found out we're on Drupal 7.56; 
also found out I have a page full of warning messages to look at ;(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This may be related to [Status page angular load error](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19366/status-page-angular-load-error/19597#19597). Make sure that the following two items point to the same place:

- **Image Upload URL** at Administer > System Settings > Resource URLS
- **Image Directory** at Administer > System Settings > Directories

If this doesn't work, try disabling **Asset Caching** at Administer > System Settings > Debugging and Error Handling until this bug is fixed.

Comment: I am having this exact same problem.  The Image upload URL and the Image Directory are the same as they should be. I disabled Asset Caching and everything appears to load properly now.  I am concerned though. Would it cause problems to operate with Asset Caching disabled?