# Can't create mailings if imageUploadDir and imageUploadURL don't match

Tags: resource-urls

I upgraded CiviCRM from 4.7.19 to 4.7.22. In the new version there is obviously a check implemented that compares imageUploadDir and imageUploadURL. Probably if they don't match after exchanging the cms.root (path and URL) it warns.

In our configuration we want to have different values here, because we provide the images from a different domain to save bandwidth to our CiviCRM server.

The problem is, that if we configure it like we want to (namely that imageUploadURL points to a different domain than CiviCRM is provided from) the form to create new bulk mails doesn't load anymore. The system status page behaves the same (it doesn't load as well as long as the two values don't match in the sense explained above).

Does anyone else observe this behaviour?

Comment: If this is of interest: CiviCRM runs on Drupal 7.56

Comment: This might relate to one of the security fixes in 4.7.22 :-( I expect it is fairly rare. If you don't get an answer here try on chat.civicr.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, related to [Status page angular load error](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19366/status-page-angular-load-error/19597#19597). Since your "Image Upload URL" and "Image Directory" are in different places, try disabling **Asset Caching** at Administer > System Settings > Debugging and Error Handling, at least until this bug is fixed.

Please also see [civimail - screen for composing a mail is blank](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19638/screen-for-composing-a-mail-is-blank)