# System Status Critical, blank System Status page

Tags: wordpress, status

After upgrading to Civi 4.7.29 on WordPress 4.9.1, it says System Status Critical (see screenshot at the bottom of this post), but the status page is blank.

The developers console in Chrome has a lot of messages similar to this:

```
GET https://mysite.org/homepages/34/d1234578/htdocs/tcp-wp/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.shoreditch/css/bootstrap.css?r=sZzwI net::ERR_ABORTED
```

I found [this](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20287/status-error-and-blank-status-page) suggesting changing directory permissions to 755, 
which I did for /wp-content/uploads/civicrm/
but it doesn't seem to have helped.

After the upgrade, I got this warning, which may be significant. However, to me these two look like two ways of saying the same thing. However, I'm not sure what I might be looking for in the htaccess file.

```
There appears to be an inconsistency in the configuration of "Image Upload URL" and "Image Upload Directory".

imageUploadDir: /homepages/34/d12345678/htdocs/tcp-wp/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/persist/contribute/
imageUploadURL: http://mysite.org/homepages/34/d12345678/htdocs/tcp-wp/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/persist/contribute/
You may need to check that:

(a) the path and URL match,
(b) the httpd/htaccess policy allows requests for files inside this folder,
and (c) the web domain matches the normal web domain.
(Note: Although files should be readable, it is best if they are not listable or browseable.)

If this remains unresolved, then some important screens may fail to load.
```

[image: system status critical]

==========================================

Tried updating resource URLs as suggested by fdarn.  Now when I click on CiviCRM on the WordPress dashboard, I get the screen shown below.  Clicking on "Configure Your Dashboard" doesn't seem to do anything.  Clicking on CiviCRM in the upper left takes me back (see red arrow below) to basically the same screen, but without that link.

Any suggestions or enlightening explanations of what's happening would be most welcome.

[image: here's where I'm at now]

Comment: Check https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20081/can-not-access-system-status-new-mailing/20083#20083

Answer (score 2):

Can you check Directory and Resource url settings if the paths are entered correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  It reminded me that I had received a warning after the upgrade that is likely important. I have added it to my original post. But I'm not sure exactly how to proceed with it.

Comment: The upgrade might have not completed properly so it would be good if you re rum it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue of our civimail and system status pages being blank after upgrading to 4.7.29.  I am also on wordpress 4.9.1.  I resolved this issue by using the absolute paths as the resource urls for images and extensions. Give that a try and see if it works. It should at least open up your system status page so you can see what needs to be upgraded or set up.

I had to upgrade our database after upgrading to civi 4.7.29.  The link to upgrade the database is in the System Status page.  That might be what your critical error is all about, but you can't get into the system status page to see that.

Try these urls for Resource URLs.  See screenshot also. Keep in mind that the system status page will need a little time to load, so if it is still blank when you first land on it, wait a little bit.

https://yoursite.org/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/persist/contribute

https://yoursite.org/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Any thoughts about what I'm seeing (added to my question)?

Comment: I have never seen that message before and now it sounds like you can't access your cividashboard either. The questions that come to mind are; have you made any changes to the core files in your previous attempts to resolve the problem? Is this install on a subdomain?