# Blank page on mailings page, cron error and no debug info | Windows Server

Tags: wordpress, error, windows

I am helping one of my non-profits with getting CIVI up and running. We are experiencing some random issues including the mailings page and the system error page are completely blank, not a white screen of death but just no data in the page.

We also have had a cron job error which I am not sure if it is important.

I have turned on debugging but again no notice of errors.

We are running in Wordpress. php 7.1. On Windows Server 2016
Thanks!

Update 12/10/2018: I have installed the system on a traditional linux server and the mailing tab initializes correctly. So I need to know what this system needs to be active for it to function. Maybe I have a missing PHP extension.

Comment: See https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20081/can-not-access-system-status-new-mailing/20083#20083 if it helps.

Comment: Do you have the Mosaico extension installed for mailings?

Comment: I am having a really rough time with this system. Nothing is straight forward. I am running a windows server and I have had dozens of sites running on it for years now without any issues. This system seems to keep needing more stuff and installation of the additional items simply is a pain in a butt. Anyways, I found the extension library and I added the extensions but all of them say they are only compliant with version 4.7 and the current version is 5.8. I tried to install Mosacio from the extension system and it says: Extension Upgrade Failed
Download failed - ZIP file is unavailable or ma

Comment: not sure that jackrabbithanna was recommending trying mosaico - more trying to understand if it was part of the problem

Comment: can you confirm what steps you have taken that were listed on jitendra's link?

Comment: Well, I have installed on a traditional Linux box and the system works perfectly out of the box. I am not sure what is missing from my windows server. This is the first time I have ever had a wordpress plugin not work when installing it on my windows server. I have been running windows servers for wordpress for the past 9 years.