# CSS and JS Files aren't loaded - CiviCRM 5.18.2 & WordPress 5.2.2

Tags: wordpress, error

Fresh install of CiviCRM on a WordPress multisite yet no interface loads on the status page - seems that all the assets throw a 404 error causing this.

Tried updating from 5.18.1 to 5.18.2 but no success.

[image]

Comment: At administer - system settings - resource url, what do you have listed there? If it says something like `[civicrm.root]`, click the help bubble at the top (in the intro text area above the settings, not beside the setting description) and it will tell you the real path that it thinks that is.

Answer (score 2):

I'm with Demerit - it looks like there's a mismatch between your Resource URL and your base directory.  Check your `$civicrm_root` in `civicrm.settings.php`.  Ensure that it is a) correct, b) doesn't contain a symlink.  If it contains a symlink, rewrite the path to be whatever the symlink(s) resolve to.

Comment: So I have to edit the plugin manually over being able to use a settings screen or similar?? Seems a bit backwards with having to do this every time I'd update the plugin....

Comment: The settings file containing the base url isn't updated when the CiviCRM files are updated. So these settings can just be made once

Comment: The `civicrm.settings.php` is the equivalent of `wp-config.php` - it doesn't get overwritten on upgrade.  Should be a quick fix.

Answer (score 2):

So after looking at this closer and working with a colleague, we found that disabling cache for the assets worked – [Status page angular load error](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19366/status-page-angular-load-error)