# After upgrading Joomla site to 5.46.2 no recipients available in mail, only 'Searching…'

Tags: wordpress, civimail, joomla, mosaico, angular

After upgrading Joomla site to 5.46.2 with Mosaico 2.9 and searchkit, there are no recipients available in mail, only showing 'Searching…' in the recipient box.

The problem disappears if debugging is turned on (see comment below from Mark, experiencing same issue in Wordpress).

There is no obviously relevant sign in the logs.

Settings files and urls/directories are clean for 'http://' references and asset caching is off.

Other angular/recipient problems resolved here have identified & resolved 'invisible' recipient groups that still operate. However, in this case, no groups present themselves to be selected.

This ONLY happens with Mosaico enabled. With Mosaico disabled, choosing of recipient groups works fine using 'traditional' interface.

Browser console shows errors:

Can't find variable: date
https://*domainname*/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/asset/builder&an=angular-modules.js&ap=TZAxbwIxDIX%2Fy81RlzJ1Ayo2JMQJdTYXc2eU2KfEoRVV%2F3sdTyx%2B78nyl9i%2FQ5bYEtbhY4DbTUoeFThCEsYAPLcE5UAJL2sSiAFW2oSp5O26uqjCtGRk9dRUKjyw%2B%2F0Pd%2Fl890rGm7s7AiXiV7vdebBBmqTbM1ZpZXLKWZrijjhi6dG%2Bpq2eYPbmhbwqpa7XL3pCiSH6WyOWBxnjXoUPthSoGiLfv%2BsCBWPg2dGmIzApPTE0eqtSFK7JfTNuDY37QnG%2F2CnsRn%2F%2F&ad=580ab1dd9c3945d0f1d6ff46614025bf:1384

and

[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: results
results (administrator:1660)
success (select2.min.js:30:322)
(anonymous function) (jquery.min.js:2:28682)
i (jquery.min.js:2:27368)
fireWith (jquery.min.js:2:28123)
x (jquery.min.js:4:22587)
c (jquery.min.js:4:26778)

Comment: Does the browser console show errors?

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks. Have amended my question.

Comment: i had a quick search on here for answers relating to angular. found this but suspect it isn't what you need but maybe it offers a hint (beyond clearing caches) https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19366/status-page-angular-load-error - you may find other Q+A here with other suggestions but assume you searched first

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Peter. That allows me a much more productive search. See new amendment.

Comment: I am seeing this on Wordpress 5.9.1 (CiviCRM 5.46.2, Mosaico 2.9.1645644008) on my prod system. My dev system is nearly identical but has Enable Debugging on. It behaved properly until I turned debugging off. I toggled Asset Caching, as mentioned in the link Pete shared, but didn't see a difference. I briefly enabled debugging on my prod system and it behaved.

Comment: I can confirm that If I turn on debugging, the problem disappears on my site too…

Comment: I see another issue. When I try to schedule a mailing and enter a date, I get "unknown path" error. It works when debugging is enabled.

Comment: I'm seeing this as well in Joomla. Had gone through the same config changes without success, until the suggestion to turn on debugging. I note that there are other console errors when a Mosaico mailing is first opened that also clear up once debugging is enabled.

Comment: I just upgraded my dev system to CiviCRM 5.47.0 and am not seeing this behavior anymore. Groups are showing up properly with debugging off.

Comment: Also working on my prod system after 5.47.0 upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

As @Mark Westergaard has observed below, the problem has disappeared upon upgrading to 5.47.0, so I guess we just put it down to an obscure temporary bug?

Problems that go away by themselves come back by themselves…

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it disappeared with 5.47.0 should be this fix https://github.com/veda-consulting-company/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/issues/494